# Wacom Intuos Pro + Illustrator CC UI bugs

Tags: adobe-illustrator, wacom, bug

I just upgraded my old Intuos to an Intuos Pro 4 (Medium).
I work on a Mac running El Capitan, and have the latest Wacom drivers.

Since i changed tablets, i noticed major bugs in Illustrator:

- After ungrouping a selection, the mouse goes from selection tool to direct selection tool.
  I cannot select paths anymore
- When resizing or moving items, "Alt" key randomly goes on/off
- Clicking outside to unselect works randomly as well
- Shift key locks

I can't understand what triggers this as it seems perfectly random so far...

Have any of you experienced similar issues?

Not sure i'm in the right place, but fear Super User has fewer Wacom users than this forum.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you since tried the old drawing tablet? This could help figure out if the problem is with the tablet/its drivers **or** if the problem is with illustrator.

Comment: sadly, it died...
I had although updated to latest drivers of former tablet, that was an intros as well...

Comment: The alt and shift key that keep malfunctioning, are they in the tablet/stylus or are you pressing them in the keyboard? If they are in the tablet, you might wanna switch to using the keyboard for a while to see if it has the same issue.

Comment: the joyful part is that i more often press nothing when it goes off.
Or i did previously, but i hit these on keyboard.

I will try deactivating all modifiers on the tablet
I'm also updating all my Creative Suite at the moment.

Comment: It does sound like it might be an issue with Illustrator then. If updating doesn't help, see if trashing the preferences helps.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the hardware supplier? I'm in doubt whether your question is tech support and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Do the problems persist if you disable touch on the Intuos?

Comment: Try the Adobe forums. They have huge myriads of complaints about Adobe software and Wacom gear. Also, in the last few years, if you have any problems with Adobe software, it's best to assume the problem is with Adobe. Adobe software development has been on a steady downwards spiral in terms of quality. They're making record profits and spending it on... well, nobody knows.

Comment: OK I'm off topic.
It happens in Photoshop and Finder as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out i have bought my Wacom in France, and had downloaded the pilots form the "world" website.

I have compared my Wacom with my neighbour's, bought in Asia.

Product reference and all were EXACTLY the same.

BUT is turns out there is some kind of locale. Driver on the French website fixed my problem...

As easy and unexpected as that...

Comment: Hi Thai, if this really was the solution to your issue, you can accept your own answer (by clicking the check mark below the up and down arrows). This way the system can close the question (else it keeps popping up on the homepage once in a while) _and_ you'll get rep.